# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stream_types"

Tags: postgresql

Below example table Stream_types gives an ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table, and having stared at it for while now I can't figure out why this error arises in this situation.

```
create table Stream_types (
id integer NOT NULL,
career careertype NOT NULL,
code character(1) NOT NULL,
description shortstring NOT NULL
);

create table Streams (
id          integer, -- PG: serial
code        char(6) not null, -- e.g. COMPA1, SENGA1
name        LongName not null,
offeredBy   integer references OrgUnits(id),
stype       ShortString references Stream_types(id),
description TextString,
firstOffer  integer references Semesters(id), -- should be not null
lastOffer   integer references Semesters(id), -- null means current
primary key (id)
);
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stream_types"
********** Error **********

ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stream_types"
SQL state: 42830
```

I'm using postgresql 9.3.16, can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Add a primary key constraint to the `id` column of the `Stream_types` table so that the referencing columns from the `Streams` table will work.

Comment: you have create so many custom types...

Comment: You should do `CONSTRAINT pkey_name PRIMARY KEY (id)` in Stream_types table. You will get same error when you try to connect other table with **Streams** table , so also change that.

Comment: But the "stype" in table "Streams" is shortstring that is not compatible with integer. Moreover, it would be better not to change the attributes' current type.

Comment: BTW, how could I import .dump file into the database in Windows system? I'm using postgresql 9.3.16 in Windows, the "pg_dump" or "psql" command doesn't work in the SQL shell of postgresql 9.3.
I am really a beginner in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

change create table Stream_types statement like here:

```
create table Stream_types (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  career careertype NOT NULL,
  code character(1) NOT NULL,
  description shortstring NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: But the "stype" in table "Streams" is shortstring that is not compatible with integer. Moreover, it would be better not to change the attributes' current type.